# How to copy UITextview through 2 UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have 2 `UIViewController`. I can go to the second View with a push style storyboard segue.

I just want to copy the First `UITextView`'s text (in the first `UIViewController`) to the second (in the second `UIViewController`) 
not just in the `prepareForSegue` but every seconds (The first `UITextView` still work even if I am in the second `ViewController`).

Comment: Please explain this: `not just in the prepareForSegue but in real time.`

Comment: I mean every time the other UItextView changes

Comment: you could to use the setter method of your textfield in viewcontroller First for notify to your second viewcontroller your changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option here would be to use reactive cocoa. You can register to be notified when a value changes  and have the text view automatically update. The source is located here :

https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa